# interpolate as3

Tags: actionscript-3, interpolation

I'm working on a project converting some source code ActionScript 3 to C#. It has the following function:

```
Point.interpolate(Point p1, Point p2, Number distance)
```

The documentation for this function is [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/Point.html#interpolate).

I want to ask how the function's algorithm works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the documentation says:

> The closer the value of the parameter f is to 1.0, the closer the interpolated point is to the first point (parameter pt1). The closer the value of the parameter f is to 0, the closer the interpolated point is to the second point (parameter pt2).

This can achieved like this:

```
public static function interpolate(pt1:Point, pt2:Point, f:Number):Point
{
     var x:Number = f * pt1.x + (1 - f) * pt2.x;
     var y:Number = f * pt1.y + (1 - f) * pt2.y;

     return new Point(x, y);
}
```

Comment: `var x:Number = pt1.x + f * (pt2.x - pt1.x)` is another way to write it (fewer multiplications, more reading of public properties... probably not a bottle neck regardless).

Comment: I just tried and the two versions have the same performance: 10000000 calls, 12378 and 12374 ms for each version. I know this depends on platforms, but I think readability is more important here. So OP can choose the version he prefers.

Comment: I ran some benchmarks (why argue when you can be sure!) and it's pretty much identical in performance (in flash that is - not sure about C#). EDIT: Benchmark'd :D

Comment: @JonatanHedborg - Yes, I already did some benchmarks myself. See my previous comment :)